# How to persist multi dimensional array with Morphia

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, morphia

I am trying to persist this class into mongodb using Morphia,

```
@Entity  
public class A {  
    @Id  
    private String id;  
    private int[][][] param = {{{0,0},{1,1}}, {{2,2},{3,3}}};  
}
```

The int array param is saved as

`[ { "className" : "[[I"} , { "className" : "[[I"}]`

No data is saved and obviously I cannot load the object.  The interesting thing is that if I put the int array in a Map, like `Map.put("param", param)`, the Map is persisted fine and the array is saved as

`[ [ [ 0 , 0] , [ 1 , 1]] , [ [ 2 , 2] , [ 3 , 3]]]`

My question is, can I persist a multi dimensional array field with Morphia?  And if yes, what is the best way?